# Receiving "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request" when uploading file to SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ssis

Im trying to upload a file to Sharepoint from a SSIS task using a C# script but I keep receiving this error message "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request". Ive done a fair bit of research and cant see from my code how Im doing it different from what others have tried. This is my code:

```
        string filePath = @"J:\test\test.xlsx";
        string libraryName = "Shared Documents";
        string siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev";
        string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in "Example0001#".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        string email = "admin@tenant.org.au";

        try
        {
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(email, passWord);
                FileCreationInformation fcInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                fcInfo.Url = fileName;
                fcInfo.Overwrite = true;
                fcInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
                List myLibrary = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                myLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Per my test, I can upload the file to sharepoint by your code. Could you share which line error: (400) occurs

Comment: It occurs on this line:

ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it accordingly

```
var file = myLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);
ctx.Load(file);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: The same error still occurs unfortunately.